# what is wrong with this Java Interface code?

Tags: java, interface

```
public interface SomethingWrong {
    public void aMethod(int value) {
        System.out.print("Hi");
    }
}
```

This is a question from my first Java quiz, and I'm kind stuck on this.

1. What is wrong with this code
2. how to fix it

Is this code wrong because interface cannot contain any method or printout method.

2nd part of the quiz is this

Is the following code valid assume the correction is made to the previous code

```
  public class Foo implements SomethingWrong {
  }

  SomethingWrong var = new Foo();
```

Comment: What error do you get? BTW you cannot declare variable `var` outside class.

Comment: If you have Java 8, you could add the `default` modifier to the method `aMethod` and this would be valid. Apart from that, depends on the Java version.

Comment: @Richard,based on the answers,it would be helpful to know which JDK you are considering.Is this a school quiz or something?if so I highly doubt it would be JDK 8

Answer (score -1):

## No. 1 Question :

```
public interface SomethingWrong {
    public void aMethod(int value) {
        System.out.print("Hi");
    }
}
```

Answer : method in interface cannot have method body .

## No. 2 Question : how to fix it

Answer :

```
public interface SomethingWrong{
    public void aMethod(int value);
}
```

Just Remove the method body and implement it so that you can override `aMethod(int value);`

## Additional 1:

```
public class MainClass implements SomethingWrong{
    //Here since you implement the interface you are now required to override it in this class. 
    // You can do it by adding a method body.
    public void aMethod(int value){
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    }
}
```

## Additional 2:

lets say you have two interface you can implement multiple of interface to a class (concrete or abstract) and you can never implement interface to another interface but you can extend a multiple interface to another interface.

## Additional 3:

You cannot create a new instance of an interface or an abstract class so it means you cannot do this:

```
SomethingWrong some = new SomethingWrong();
```

because interface dont have a constructor. correct me if im wrong :))

Comment: I think **SomethingWrong var = new Foo();** is correct,

we are creating an instance on **Foo** with a reference to SomethingWrong

Comment: yes it is correct i used it recently in spring :) you can reference class using a interface

Answer (score -1):

add `default` keyword and it will work with Java 8 compiler:

```
public interface SomethingWrong {
    default public void aMethod(int value) {
        System.out.print("Hi");
    }
}
```